# Get data from last 2 months and current month

Tags: datetime, dynamic-sql, interbase

I need to get all the checks from last month and the current month in InterBase, I have looked into the documentation for this but I am not able to see why it keep falling and I keep getting an error saying that month is not been recognized. Any guidance is more than helpful since I am not pinging this issue correctly.

Dynamic SQL Error, SQL Error =-104, Token unknown, char 30, month.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TRANSACTION
WHERE Paid_CHECK_DATE > dateadd (month, -2, 'NOW') 

SELECT * 
FROM TRANSACTION
WHERE Paid_CHECK_DATE > dateadd (-2, month, 'NOW')
```

Results:

All checks for the past 2 months and current month

Comment: This seems to have nothing to do with Firebase, so I'm removing that tag. If your question is actually related to Firebase, please add details to the description.

Answer (score 0):

`DATEADD` is not a valid Interbase function. You simply add/subtract the number of days from a date (e.g. `current_date-60` )

Answer (score 0):

For 1 month try:

```
SELECT 
  NAME, 
  MY_DATEFIELD 
FROM MY_TABLE 
WHERE 
  ((EXTRACT(MONTH FROM MY_DATEFIELD) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE)+11)
  OR (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM MY_DATEFIELD) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE)-1)) 
  AND (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MY_DATEFIELD) >= EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE)-1)
```

Bit wonky but works great.
So If My_DATEFIELD is 2 and today is march you will not find it with current month+11, current month-1 will. (and the current year is equal or less than 1 year old)
If My_DATEFIELD is 12 and today is January, current month + 11 will be 12 that is  correct, current month-1 is 0 so there will be no month there, and the year is current year minus 1.
You get the idea how to modify this for 2 months....